# Split one Subject into different Subjects depending on the data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observer-pattern

I have a APIService that connects to a websocket using another service. The websocket service returns a socket of type `Subject<MessageEvent>`. Then in my APIService I would like to spit this Subject into different Subjects depending on the payload. My APIService looks like this:

```
export class APIService {

  public sonos: Subject<sonosData>;
  public commits: Subject<commitData>;

  constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
    this.sonos = <Subject<sonosData>>wsService
      .connect(WEBSOCKET_URL)
      .map((response: MessageEvent) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        if(data.sonos) {
          return data.sonos;
        }
      });
  }

}
```

Is there another operator instead of `map` that I can use? If I write some sudo code for this it would look like this:

```
export class APIService {

  public sonos: Subject<sonosData>;
  public commits: Subject<commitData>;

  constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
    wsService
      .connect(WEBSOCKET_URL)
      .forEach((response: MessageEvent) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        if(data.sonos) {
          this.sonos = data.sonos;
        }
        if(data.commits) {
          this.commits = data.commits;
        }
      });
  }

}
```

But then the public variables wont be defined and cause an error since my components using them can't subscribe to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to initialize empty subjects and get other components subscribe to the subjects like this:

```
sonos = new Rx.Subject()
commits = new Rx.Subject();
```

Next, when you get back the data, you can do something like this

```
 wsService
      .connect(WEBSOCKET_URL)
      .forEach((response: MessageEvent) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        if(data.sonos) {
         this.sonos.onNext(data.sonos);
        }
        if(data.commits) {
          this.commits.onNext(data.commits);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, the onNext method didn't work for me. But the method next worked, probably works the same right?

Comment: Yeah. I wrote the code snippet using Javascript implementation, probably Typescript is a little bit different. The main point it worked for you.